# How to clear the REPLACEBATT state from APC UPS after hot-swapping the battery

Tags: ups

I replaced a battery in APC SmartUPS by hot-swapping. While the swap was all right and didn't disturb connected computers, the "Battery failed" LED on the front face kept glowing.

I tried to use `apctest` from `apcups` package. Turned off the daemon and run self test (first changing BATTDATE in EEPROM). The test run fine but didn't clear the `REPLACEBATT` status or the glowing LED.

How to clear the failed battery state without powering the UPS and connected equipment down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To clear this status one needs to run the self test using the **Test** button on front panel.

Comment: In my case (using an APC model BR900GI) the front panel has only three buttons and no dedicated button labeled Test. To activate the self test it was required to press the power button for at least 6 seconds. Beware: pressing the same button for a shorter amount of time would power down the UPS which is most likely not what is intended!

Answer (score 3):

You have to run a valid self test for the LED to clear. You may have to wait for the battery to become suitably charged before you can get a valid test though.

There is some information [**here**](http://www.apc.com/support/badbattery/SU_self_test.cfm) about it.

Comment: It could be because the `apctest` does a deep discharge (to 25% or 10 minutes) while the front panel does a quick test (about 10-15 seconds). And then the old battery performance (in my case it was 2.5 year old) will be used as a capacity estimator.